# подскажите алгоритм решения задачи

Tags: алгоритм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Совсем запутался с этой задачей: не понимаю как найти следующий элемент в последовательности, если известен только 1 элемент всей последовательности.

PS Код не нужен! Нужен только сам алгоритм: какое значение берем, что с ним делаем и т.д.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: чтобы ваш вопрос мог бы быть полезен не только вам, добавьте текст задачи в виде текста. Чтобы не тратить время напрасно будущих читателей, составьте более информативный заголовок нежели *"подскажите алгоритм решения задачи"* [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любой N-ый элемент последовательности, начиная с 3-его вычисляется по формуле `H[n]=2H[n-1]+2-H[n-2]`. НО, не надо поиск второго элемента ставить как задачу номер один. Да, он нам понадобится, сильно. Но начать решение задачи следует с поиска номера такой лампочки, которая касается земли.

И так, у нас есть формула для получения N-го элемента из двух предыдущих, но два предыдущих элемента получаются из тех, что стоят перед ними. Пусть `A` означает нулевой элемент последовательности (H[0]), а `B` первый элемент (H[1]). Тогда второй элемент равен `H[2]=2B+2-A`. А третий элемент тогда равен:

```
H[3]=2*H[2]+2-B
H[3]=2*(2B+2-A)+2-B
H[3]=4B+4-2A+2-B
H[3]=3B+6-2A
```

Выразив таким образом еще пару элементов и посмотрев как они образуются, получаем общую формулу N-ого элемента, выраженного через первые два: `H[N]=N*B-A*(N-1)+N*(N-1)`. Тогда зная номер лампочки (`N`), которая касается земли, и нулевой элемент последовательности мы можем вычислить первый элемент (`B`):

```
N*B-A*(N-1)+N*(N-1)=0
N*B=A*(N-1)-N*(N-1)
B=( A*(N-1)-N*(N-1) ) / N
```

Теперь нам надо подобрать такое N, что бы H[N] было равно нулю и при этом она была самой низкой точкой нашей кривой. Т.е. ее соседи слева и справа должны быть больше 0. Вот тут как раз нам понадобится [метод дихотомии](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B8), который рекомендуют использовать в задаче. Начнем с диапазона лампочек длиной во всю гирлянду. Nstart=0, Nend=длина_гирлянды. Принимаем за `N` лампочку в середине участка от Nstart до Nend. Исходя из него вычислим `B`. Зная `A` и `B` вычислим высоту предыдущей (H[N-1]) и следующей (H[N+1]) лампочек. Если предыдущая лампочка, оказалась ниже уровня земли, значит мы нашли 0 на восходящей части кривой и нам надо искать минимум левее, принимаем Nend=N. Если следующая лампочка оказывается ниже нуля, то мы попали на нисходящую часть кривой (до ее середины) и нам надо искать правее - выставляем Nstart=N. Если обе лампочки оказались выше нуля, значит мы находимся уже близко к цели, но возможно оптимальную точку еще не нашли. Стоит проверить чуть правее, контролируя что бы при этом соседи оставались выше нуля.

Comment: вопрос по поводу 1 формулы: разве не `h[n] = 2h[n-1] + 2 - h[n-2]`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Да, спасибо, опечатка, ниже она уже без лишней 2 была :)

Comment: спасибо - сам тоже пытался решить через тот элемент, который должен равняться нулю, но не смог вывести формулу. А из-за того, что в условии сказано "может касаться" - вообще подумал, что нулевого элемента может не быть... вообщем большое спасибо)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Да, меня это условие кстати то же напрягало, но потом я подумал, что если текущая кривая не касается земли, то это явно не минимум для второй точки, потому что ее можно опускать до тех пор пока не коснется

Comment: забавно, но это, оказывается, не решение задачи....

Comment: точнее с этой задачей наложали те кто ее создавал) Я написал код под нее на основе вышеизложенного, но оказалось, что в задаче не соблюдено условие самой задачи!!!! Есть места, где нулевые элементы могут стоять рядом друг с другом... И, походу, я первый кто это заметил

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch вы имеете ввиду, что есть несколько точек подходящих под условия ? так надо брать ту, что дает более низкую высоту второго конца

Comment: нет, я имею ввиду что создатели налажали: может быть не один 0 на два! Тоесть может быть последовательность: 2 0 0 2

Comment: это хорошо видно из условия, где дано: n = 5 и A = 12